# Toggling Button States

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button

I am attempting to implement toggling functionality into a program I am working on. Specifically, there are 3 possible scenarios when a user clicks a button.

1. Tool clicked while no other tool is currently active.
2. Tool clicked while another tool is currently active
3. Same tool is clicked to toggle it on/off

I am having trouble implementing this. Here is my code so far:

```
var toolState = {
    img_draw_point: false,
    img_draw_line: false,
    img_draw_rectangle: false,
    img_draw_ellipse: false,
    img_draw_FreehandPolygon: false,
    img_draw_FreehandPolyline: false,
    img_draw_text: false,
    img_draw_eraser: false,
};

var lastActiveTool;

on(dom.byId("div-tools-draw"), "click", function (evt) {
        function disableActiveCSS() {
            for (var property in toolState) {

                $("img#" + property + ".k-button.single").removeClass("buttonSelected");
                $("img#" + property + ".k-button.single").removeClass("buttonHoverState");
            }
        }

        function enableCSS() {
            $("img#" + evt.target.id + ".k-button.single").addClass("buttonSelected");
            $("img#" + evt.target.id + ".k-button.single").addClass("buttonHoverState");
        }

        toolState[evt.target.id] = !toolState[evt.target.id];
        if (toolState[evt.target.id] == toolState[lastActiveTool]) {
            toolState[lastActiveTool] = false;
        }

        disableActiveCSS();
        enableCSS();

        if (evt.target.id == lastActiveTool) {
            disableActiveCSS();
        }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your function `on` and object `dom` are these just aliases for jQuery's `on` method and `document` object? Also `byId` is that an alias of getElementById?

Comment: Forgot to mention, the button "click" event is handled by Dojo. This is not by choice, it is a specification set by our client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your code contains the '$' notation so I used jQuery in my response. It also assumes that we only care if another tool is currently "ON". So the 3 options in my response are:

1. Turn on the selected tool if no tool is on.
2. Turn off the current tool and turn on the selected tool.
3. Turn off the current tool if it is currently on.

```js
var lastActiveTool = false;

$.click("#div-tools-draw", function(evt) {
  // Disable Active CSS
  $("img.k-button.single").removeClass("buttonSelected").removeClass("buttonHoverState");

  if (!lastActiveTool) {
    activateTool(evt.target.id);
  } else if (evt.target.id == lastActiveTool) {
    sameToolToggle(evt.target.id);
  } else {
    otherToolToggle(evt.target.id);
  }

};

var activateTool = function (id) {
  $("img#" + id + ".k-button.single").addClass("buttonSelected")addClass("buttonHoverState");
  lastActiveTool = evt.target.id;
};

var otherToolToggle = function(id) {
  $("img#" + id + ".k-button.single").addClass("buttonSelected")addClass("buttonHoverState");
  lastActiveTool = evt.target.id;
  // Whatever else you need to do to toggle between tools
}

// Only gets called when the same tool is currently toggled ON
var sameToolToggle = function(id) {
  lastActiveTool = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was so helpful.